# Как преобразовать string в char c++?

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
    if(isalpha(rus_alphabet[_indexOfSymbol(text[i], rus_alphabet, rus_size)])) {
        count_of_symbols[_indexOfSymbol(text[i], rus_alphabet,rus_size)] += 1;
    }
}
```

Если элемент массива `rus_alphabet`, с индексом `_indexOfSymbol(функция, которая возвращает индекс элемента)` - является буквой, то прибавить 1.
Проблема в том, что `isalpha` работает только для char, а я никак не могу преобразовать `string` в `char(не char* )`, чтобы их сравнить.
P.S. `string` хранит одну букву. Я сравниваю всю строку, а не посимвольно. `String` это элемент массива строк!

`rus_alphabet` имеет следующий вид: `rus_alphabet[0] = "А";`

Comment: Совершенно ничего не понятно. Какой тип элемента массива rus_alphabet?

Comment: Вы, наверное, издеваетесь. Ладно, повторю:
rus_alphabet имеет следующий вид:
rus_alphabet[0] = "А";

Comment: @rus_alphabet П зачем вы пытаетесь тогда применить функцию isalpha к строке? И почему не объявить массив rus_alphabet как символьный массив? Или вы создаете специально себе трудности, чтобы затем их успешно преодолевать?

Comment: Потому что я не знаю как должно быть, поэтому и спрашиваю, т.к. `isalpha` применяется к `char`.

Comment: @ kot_mapku3 Ваше пример кода неверный,  так как не ясно, как объявлены переменные.

Comment: Попробуйте написать ЧТО вам нужно, конкретно. Из того что вы написали можно гадать что вам нужно - то ли количество букв в строке, то ли что-то еще.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вопрос только в том, как получить из `std::string` первый символ как `char`, то можно:

```
string s = "a";
char c1 = s.c_str()[0]; // так
char c2 = *s.c_str(); // или так
char c3 = s[0]; // вариант alexolut
```

Comment: Оно так не работает с русскими символами

Comment: С русскими будет работать std::wstring и wchar_t вместо std::string и char. Соответственно вам надо будет использовать iswalpha вместо обычной isalpha

Comment: @DanielProtopopov а много изменится, если я поменяю код на wstring?

Comment: Конечно много потому что обычный char не сможет в себя вместить кириллицу, только английские 8битные символы.

Comment: @kot_mapku3 Так может вы тогда сформулируете вопрос нормально? На вопрос "Проблема в том, что isalpha работает только для char, а я никак не могу преобразовать string в char" я вроде как дал ответ, а что вы там реально пытаетесь сделать мы так и не выяснили, ни примера входных данных, ни выходных, вы нам не дали, а телепаты все в отпуске.

Comment: @kot_mapku3 И да, разберитесь таки с тем, что для вас русские символы. Вон в [CP1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B0_Windows-1251_.28.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BC_CP1251.29) вполне себе есть символы кирилицы, и даже в `char` все помещается.

Comment: @Flowneee да хорошо, ответ принят, я чуть позже лучше напишу полный и подробный вопрос касательно русских символов и wstring, wchar.

Comment: Зачем здесь `c_str`? Можно ведь просто `s[0]`.

Comment: @alexolut спасибо, не знал что для строк можно по индексу обращаться, сейчас добавлю

Comment: Точку с запятой не забудьте в конце.

Comment: @alexolut Done.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov string замечательно любой текст может хранить (как последовательность байтов в соответствующей кодировке, к примеру, utf-8). Отдельный байт (которых всего 256), конечно не может уникально весь миллион Unicode символов представить. Также не обязательно что и wchar_t целиком букву содержит (даже на системе где wchar_t 4, а не 2 байта), к примеру, буква `ё` в зависимости от нормализации может более одной Unicode codepoint занимать. Не BMP символы (некоторые смайлики к примеру) в два байта не поместятся.

Comment: @Flowneee чтобы с Unicode работать в C++, посмотрите на список возможных проблем и пути их решения на http://utf8everywhere.org/ (в качестве обзора как это на практике может выглядеть)